# Where is the error in this MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, syntax, coldfusion

I've been sat for hours trying to find the problem with MySQL syntax that [ColdFusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_ColdFusion) is telling me I have, but I can't see it. Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM message_table
WHERE useridto = #session.userid# AND read = 0
```

The error I'm getting is telling me:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'read = '0''
>   at line 4"

And I have researched MySQL, checked past queries I have done that have IDENTICAL syntax and work. Have I missed something simple?

I should probably mention that `#session.userid#` does output properly, so it isn't that.

Comment: Are you wrapping the values with apostrophes `' '`? e.g. read = '0'?

Comment: The query you typed doesn't match the query in the error. I see a difference of `read = 0` from `read = '0'` in the error message. Which is it?

Comment: yes sorry, I had tried with and without and found no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`read` is a reserved keyword in MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

This could cause issues as well. I would change your column name OR do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM message_table
WHERE useridto = #session.userid# AND `read` = 0
```

> An identifier may be quoted or
>   unquoted. If an identifier contains
>   special characters or is a reserved
>   word, you must quote it whenever you
>   refer to it
>   The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):

per: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html

Comment: In CF, surrounding a variable with '#' will output the variable's value.

Comment: CF might properly qualify the `session.userid` with quotes when it does the replacement. My guess is `read` being a keyword or wrapping an integer in quotes is the problem.

Comment: I don't think `#session.userid#` is his issue, since the MySQL error occurs at the `read = '0'`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys. I think the answer above where read is a reserved word must be the problem as I have found if I am more specific with my field name (message_table.read) then it is quite happy.

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck Sean!

Comment: 'read' = 0 compares the string "read" to 0, which is false. You mean `read` = 0 (backticks) which compare a field named read to 0. Can you edit you answer?

Comment: Thank you for changing that, Im away from my computer right now

Answer (score 3):

`read` is a MySQL keyword. Try surrounding it with backquotes (`):

```
SELECT * FROM message_table WHERE useridto = 5 AND `read` = 0
```